# How to make a one option value in select to find any value

Tags: php, mysql

This is the example table for the project:

TBL_TEST:

```
id     -
reference   -
reciever   -
created-
```

this is the view , after adding the class and including all the required files, like db_con and class initializations, and createing new object.

```
$refone = $_POST['refone'];
$reftow = $_POST['reftow'];
$ref3= $documentout->get_ref($refone,$reftow);
foreach($ref3 as $ref):
    echo "this is test ".$ref['reference']."--------" .$ref['reciever']. "<br />";
endforeach;
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <lable>select_ref1</lable>
      <select name="refone">
        <option value=''>all</option>
        <option value='1'>one</option>
       <option value='2'>tow</option>
      </select>
    <lable>select_ref2</lable>
      <select name="reftow">
        <option value=''>all</option>
        <option value='1'>one</option>
       <option value='2'>tow</option>
      </select></form>
```

this is the function for echo the result:

```
public function get_ref($refone, $reftow) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM '. self::$table_name . ' WHERE reference = :refone AND reciever = :reftow';
        $sth = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $sth->bindParam('refone', $refone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam('reftow', $reftow, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        return $row = $sth -> fetchAll();
    }
```

Now her is the idia, i want to echo **reference = %whatever% and reciever=%whatever%**
means the all in select or both select so it should result all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the value that you are passing on option All. If you do not want to change your php code you should try

> ```
> <option value="%">all</option>
> ```

Comment: Use LIKE operator in mysql query instead of = operator and enclose the % value in single quotes

Comment: yes, but you know this if i use like it will show, like values, for example(1, 122, 112) now if i do like 1, it will show all but i want exact one, not like,,,,example, reciever(1,12,13,14) reference(11,1,12,13) if i do ((reference=1 AND reciever=%) no result

Comment: it will show all the values only when you use % with 1. if you use LIKE '1' then it will give only 1. But if you use LIKE '%1%' then it will return 1, 122, 112

Comment: it worked for me but dont know if i change some complex queries will work or not, any how thanks, and wish puting(%) not have any security risk

Answer (score 1):

Do some logic to make query as you like, one solution could be with ifs to configure it (like two previous answers". What I recommend to you is to use PDO to create the query. Can you see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Example final query string and executing it:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ref1 = :ref1 AND ref2 = :ref2';
$sth = $db->prepare($query);
$sth->bindParam('ref1', $ref1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam('ref2', $ref2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
sth->execute();
```

Comment: here i have used PDO, this question was example not actual code, as you know such get is very unsecur, so i havent use same code in actual application but i want an option value that could select any. an trying the answers

Answer (score 0):

Do it a little different and create your sql statement on the fly so

change your `<option value="">all</option>` to be `<option value="all">all</option>`

then use a series of if statements

```
if ($_GET['ref1']!="all")  {
   //nothing comes before this so you can not worry about an AND
   $ref1sql = "ref1 =" . $_GET['ref1'];
}


if ($_GET['ref2']!="all")  {
   //so we have a ref2 here check if there's a ref  1
   if ($_GET['ref1']!="all")  {
       //we have a ref1 so need an and
       $ref2sql = " AND ref2 =" . $_GET['ref2'];
   } else {
       $ref2sql = "ref2 =" . $_GET['ref2'];
   }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST WHERE $ref1sql $ref2sql";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `all` option value like this

```
<option value='all'>all</option>
```

In your `php`

```
$ref1 = $ref2 = 1;

if($_GET['ref1'] != '' && $_GET['ref1'] != 'all') {
   $ref1 = 'ref1 = ' . $_GET['ref1'];
}

if($_GET['ref2'] != '' && $_GET['ref2'] != 'all') {
   $ref2 = 'ref2 = ' . $_GET['ref2'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST WHERE $ref1 AND $ref2 ";
```